# vuejs declaring active properties inside of a component for vue router

Tags: vue.js

I am using vue.js 2 and I am simply building a template for my component. Issue is getting that data to work for the component. I had to build the component for the route. I moved all of my code inside of a a return function and I still get an error that the properties are not defined and look up declaring reactive properties. The properties are indeed defined. Can anyone see what I am missing inside of this data function?

```js
const regTemplate = {
            template: '#reg',
            data: function() {     
                return { 
                    title: 'Regulatory',
                    name:'',
                    category:'',
                    date:'',
                    name:''
                }
            },
            methods: {
                initDatas: function () {
                    var myTitle = this.$route.params.year;
                    var  Root= 'http://example.com';
                    var headers = {
                        accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    }
                    var vm = this;
                    var myTitle = this.$route.params.year;
                    $.ajax({
                        url:  Root + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + myTitle + "')/items?&$orderby=Created desc",
                        type: 'Get',
                        headers: headers,
                        success: function (data) {
                            vm.items = data.d.results;
                            console.log(vm.items)
                        }

                    })
                },
            },
            mounted: function () {
                this.initDatas();
                alert("this");
            }
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: where is property "items" in your data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Binding data to vue for axios call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57781637/binding-data-to-vue-for-axios-call)

Answer (score 1):

You're using `vm.items`, so you need to define it in your data function.

For example:

```
 data: function() {
    return { 
      title: 'Regulatory',
      name:'',
      category:'',
      date:'',
      name:'',
      items: []
    }
  },
```